# Partial order on power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say $A = {1, 2, 3, 4}$

How can I show that $⊆$ is a partial order on $P(A)$?

Would I still have to show that it's reflexive/anti-symmetric/transitive?

I'm just confused on how to apply partial orders on power sets.

Comment: You have to show the definition is satisfied. Whatever your definition may be.

Comment: You are not applying partial order on power sets. You are applying partial order on the elements of the power set. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: Partial orders on power sets work exactly the same way as partial orders on any other sets. It's just that those elements you compare happen to themselves be sets.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall B \in P(A), B \subseteq B$$

Hence it is reflexive.

$$\forall B, C \in P(A), B \subseteq C \wedge C \subseteq B \implies B=C.$$

Hence it is antisymmetry.

$$\forall B, C, D \in P(A), B \subseteq C \wedge C \subseteq D \implies B \subseteq D.$$

Hence it is transitive.